# Inconsistent behavior of QSqlTableModel with OnRowSubmit

Tags: python, sqlite, qt, pyqt, qsqltablemodel

<sup>Premise: this question *possibly* refers to two distinct problems, but I believe they *might* be linked. If, after comments and further research we will find out that they are actually unrelated, I will open a separate question.</sup>

I'm experiencing some unexpected and odd behavior with some aspects of QSqlTableModel, and with subclassing in at least one case. I'm not an expert on Sql, but one of the problems doesn't seem what the expected behavior should be.

I can confirm this only for SQLite as I don't use other database systems.
I can also reproduce these problems with both [Py]Qt 5.15.2 and 6.2.2.

### 1. New row is "removed" after ignoring editor changes

With the default `OnRowChange` edit strategy, if a row is added, some data is inserted in a field, and editing of *another* field on the same row is cancelled using <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the *whole* row is then removed from the view.

The actual database, though, is still updated, and opening the program again shows the row that was previously "hidden", except for the field that has been cancelled.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql

class TestModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        QtSql.QSqlQuery().exec(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name, value, data);')
        self.setTable('test')
        self.select()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('test.db')
db.open()

win = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(win)
addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add row')
layout.addWidget(addButton)
table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
layout.addWidget(table)
model = TestModel()
table.setModel(model)

addButton.clicked.connect(lambda: model.insertRow(model.rowCount()))
app.aboutToQuit.connect(model.submitAll)

win.resize(640, 480)
win.show()
app.exec()
```

These are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. add a row with the button;
2. edit at least one field, but *not* all fields;
3. start editing an empty field;
4. press <kbd>Esc</kbd>;
5. close and restart the program;

After step 4, you'll see that the added row is removed from the view, which is not completely unexpected: since the strategy is `OnRowChange`, cancelling reverts all cached changes (including `insertRow()`); I don't completely agree with the behavior (imagine filling dozens of fields and then hitting Esc by mistake), but that's not the point.
What's unexpected is that the model *is actually updated* with the new row and all fields that have been submitted before hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and restarting the program will show that.

### 2. Implementing `data()` reverts to previous data for incomplete records

Editing an index that has empty (`NULL`) fields for its row brings different results whether `data()` has been implemented or not in the subclass, *even if the override just calls the base implementation*.

Add the following to the `TestModel` class above:

```py
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        return super().data(index, role)
```

And a submit button before `app.exec()`:

```py
submitButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit')
layout.addWidget(submitButton)
submitButton.clicked.connect(model.submitAll)
```

To reproduce the problem follow these steps:

1. open a database with at least one row with an empty field at the bottom, similarly to what done above (note: with "empty field" I mean an item that has *never* been edited);
2. edit any field in that row and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;

With the `OnRowChange` or `OnFieldChange` strategy, the result is that the whole row is made invalid: the vertical header shows "!" (a hint for an invalid record) and ***all*** fields are cleared, including those that have previous value from the database.

When the edit strategy is set to `OnManualSubmit`, calling `submitAll()` will revert to the original values of the database, just like as changes have been reverted.

The behavior is slightly different if the row with the empty field is *not* at the bottom; do the first two steps above, then:

3. press the submit button;
4. close and restart the program;

In this case, after step 3 the view seem to have accepted the changes, but restarting the program shows that no modification has been applied.

---

Depending on the edit strategy and the situation, the behavior changes. Usually, if a record with an empty field is followed by at least a record with all fields set, the view and model behave as expected when cancelling editing of that field.
In at least one case it was even impossible to edit an empty field at all (I've to admit, I did many random/speed tests and when I found out that I wasn't able to edit a field I couldn't remember the steps to reproduce it).

What's also strange is that both `setData()` and `submitAll()` return `True`, and there is no explicit `lastError()`. Despite of that, the shown (and stored) data reverts to the previous database content.

I believe that both issues are potentially caused by a common bug, but, before submitting something to the Qt bug report system I'd like to have some feedback, especially from people being more experienced in SQL and other db drivers, in order to provide a better report (and eventually know if those issues are in fact related or not).

Comment: After experimenting with this again, I found the behaviour has changed quite considerably. This happened after I made an extensive update of my arch linux system, which included some upgrades of qt5 and pyqt5 (amongst many other things). I can now reproduce many of the problems mentioned in your question. For the record, I was previously using qt5-base 5.15.2+kde+r263-1 and I'm now using qt5-base 5.15.2+kde+r268-1. Since this has made most of my earlier comments obsolete, I've deleted them.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you a lot for your previous comments (which I read, but I didn't had enough time or focus to get back to you yet [sorry about that] and I didn't want to add unnecessary comments until I was able to provide a valid response). From your last comment it seems that the behavior wasn't changed due to the actual Qt version, but from the "mix" of the configuration, which puzzles me even more: AFAIK Qt uses its own drivers, but I always thought that those were directly "bundled" in the distribution and their development centralized along with the rest of the framework.

Comment: @ekhumoro unfortunately, as said, I can only test this with SQLite, are you able to check if the same behavior is consistent with other drivers too? I'd like to understand if the problem comes from the QtSqlQuery/Table model implementation, it is related to the driver, or even a combination of them. Also, I presume that you're mostly referring to the second problem, while the first remains a bit more "conceptual" (the fact that the whole row is cancelled, a behavior I don't agree with, but is at least a bit more coherent with the documentation). Can you confirm any of that?

Comment: Before discussing this more, I think it's vital to know what platform you are testing on, and the exact version of qt5 you are using. On arch linux, this has been complicated by all the kde patches that have been applied since qt-5.15.2 was released. Are you using a vanilla qt5, or some kind of patched version?

Comment: Just to be clear: I'm talking about [this patch collection](https://community.kde.org/Qt5PatchCollection), which became necessary after the [LTS version of Qt5 became commercial only](https://www.qt.io/blog/commercial-lts-qt-5.15.3-released).

Comment: @ekhumoro I can confirm the same behavior on a very old Gentoo Linux (which probably was custom-built due to the nature of that distro) with Qt 5.7.1 and with a newer and pretty updated Lubuntu (Ubuntu reference version is 21.04) with Qt 5.15.2 (which uses standard packages from Ubuntu).

Comment: Okay, so that probably explains why we're not always seeing the exact same things. I will try do some more experimentation tomorrow and confirm the behaviour I am now seeing.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you a lot! Btw, I'm not in a hurry and I'm aware that this kind of issues are not easy to deal with: if you're on vacation, take your time and enjoy your holydays... and Best Wishes! :-)

Comment: I now have a firm diagnosis of both issues which should allow you to make the necessary bug reports. However, please test everything thoroughly first using the test-script in my answer. The issues I reported above after updating my system were temporary and are no longer relevant. I think it should now be clear from my answer why there were some difficulties in reproducing the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Both issues are caused by bugs in Qt, but they aren't related.

Before explaining these issues, some clarification of the symbols used in the vertical header may be helpful, because they provide some important clues regarding the source of the problems. The symbols are [documented thus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-presenting.html):

> If you insert rows programmatically using
> QSqlTableModel::insertRows(), the new rows will be marked with an
> asterisk (*) until they are submitted using submitAll() or
> automatically when the user moves to another record (assuming the edit
> strategy is QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange). Likewise, if you remove rows
> using removeRows(), the rows will be marked with an exclamation mark
> (!) until the change is submitted.

The first issue is caused by this sequence of events:

After pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> whilst editing a new row (i.e. `*` is shown in the vertical header), the delegate will emit `closeEditor` with the [RevertModelCache](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#EndEditHint-enum) hint. This calls the `closeEditor` slot of the view, which in turn calls `revert()` on the table-model - and also, ultimately, the private [revertCachedRow](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/models/qsqltablemodel.cpp.html#_ZN21QSqlTableModelPrivate15revertCachedRowEi) function. This function calls `beginRemoveRows` - but crucially *before* clearing the cache. Next, `rowsAboutToBeRemoved` is emitted, which removes the row from the view, causing `currentRowChanged` to be emitted, which in turn calls the `submit()` slot of the table-model. Oops! The still uncleared cache data is now inadvertently committed to the database, before `endRemoveRows` is called after the cache data is finally removed. So, in short, the bug here is that there is no guard to stop `submit()` being called during the execution of `revert()`.

The second issue is much more subtle. The problem occurs because the SQL table is created without a primary key and the columns do not have an explicit type. This is all perfectly valid, but it exposes a critical bug in a small section of Qt code that builds SQL statements.

This happens in [QSqlTableModel::selectRow](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/models/qsqltablemodel.cpp.html#_ZN14QSqlTableModel9selectRowEi), which needs to build a where-clause from the `QSqlRecord` returned by [primaryValues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#primaryValues). The [sqlStatement](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriver.html#sqlStatement) function of the database driver is used for this, but that needs to know the exact type of the field values in order to quote them correctly. However, the table-model cache does not ensure that a sensible default type is used for columns without an explicit type. This means untyped values will pass through unquoted, allowing arbitrary SQL expressions to be evaluated whilst editing the table. Oops!

It's this that can sometimes make the bug hard to reproduce, because the exact behaviour depends on the precise values that are entered. A value like `foo` will cause an SQL error, because it's a valid column name that doesn't exist; yet a value like `6` won't raise an error, but *will* wrongly fail to return any rows, due to a type-mismatch (i.e. `INT` *vs* `TEXT`). If `selectRow` can't find the relevant row, it may call [cache.refresh()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/models/qsqltablemodel_p.h.html#_ZN21QSqlTableModelPrivate11ModifiedRow7refreshEbRK10QSqlRecord), which will clear the values and mark the row for deletion (hence the `!` shown in the vertical header). Note also that `QSqlQuery` is used to execute the problematic statement, so any errors will pass silently and won't be available via the database or driver.

I have provided a re-write below of the original example with some fixes that can be switched on via the command-line (`1` to fix the first issue, `2` to fix the second, and `3` to fix both). These are mainly meant for debugging, but could also be adapted as work-arounds if required. The second fix is rather hackish (because `primaryValues` can't be reimplemented in PyQt) - but it's only needed if you don't have control over the database schema. If the table has a typed primary key and/or all the columns have an explicit type, the second issue won't occur at all. Hopefully the output from the script should make it clear what is going on.

**PyQt5**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql

BUGFIX = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 0

class TestModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._select_row = None
        self._reverting = False
        QtSql.QSqlQuery().exec(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name, value, data);')
        self.setTable('test')
        self.select()

    def selectRow(self, row):
        if BUGFIX & 2:
            self._select_row = row
        result = super().selectRow(row)
        print(f'selectRow: {result}')
        return result

    def select(self):
        return super().select() if self._select_row is None else False

    def selectStatement(self):
        if self._select_row is not None:
            record = self.primaryValues(self._select_row)
            for index in range(record.count()):
                field = record.field(index)
                if (not field.isNull() and
                    field.type() == QtCore.QVariant.Invalid):
                    field.setType(QtCore.QVariant.String)
                    record.replace(index, field)
            where = self.database().driver().sqlStatement(
                QtSql.QSqlDriver.WhereStatement,
                self.tableName(), record, False)
            if where[:6].upper() == 'WHERE ':
                where = where[6:]
            self.setFilter(where)
            self._select_row = None
        statement = super().selectStatement()
        print(f'selectStatement: {statement!r}')
        query = self.database().exec(statement)
        if query.lastError().isValid():
            print(f'  query-lastError: {query.lastError().text()!r}')
        else:
            print(f'  query-next: {query.next()}')
        return statement

    def revert(self):
        if BUGFIX & 1:
            self._reverting = True
        print('reverting ...')
        super().revert()
        self._reverting = False
        print('reverted')

    def submit(self):
        print('submitting ...')
        result = False if self._reverting else super().submit()
        print(f'submitted: {result}')
        return result

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('test.db')
db.open()

win = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(win)
addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add row')
layout.addWidget(addButton)
table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
layout.addWidget(table)
model = TestModel()
table.setModel(model)
submitButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit')
layout.addWidget(submitButton)
submitButton.clicked.connect(model.submitAll)
addButton.clicked.connect(lambda: model.insertRow(model.rowCount()))
app.aboutToQuit.connect(model.submitAll)

win.setGeometry(1000, 50, 640, 480)
win.show()
app.exec()
```

**PyQt6**:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql

BUGFIX = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 0

class TestModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._select_row = None
        self._reverting = False
        QtSql.QSqlQuery().exec(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name, value, data);')
        self.setTable('test')
        self.select()

    def selectRow(self, row):
        if BUGFIX & 2:
            self._select_row = row
        result = super().selectRow(row)
        print(f'selectRow: {result}')
        return result

    def select(self):
        return super().select() if self._select_row is None else False

    def selectStatement(self):
        if self._select_row is not None:
            record = self.primaryValues(self._select_row)
            MetaType = QtCore.QMetaType.Type
            MetaString = QtCore.QMetaType(MetaType.QString.value)
            for index in range(record.count()):
                field = record.field(index)
                if (not field.isNull() and
                    field.metaType().id() == MetaType.UnknownType.value):
                    field.setMetaType(MetaString)
                    record.replace(index, field)
            where = self.database().driver().sqlStatement(
                QtSql.QSqlDriver.StatementType.WhereStatement,
                self.tableName(), record, False)
            if where[:6].upper() == 'WHERE ':
                where = where[6:]
            self.setFilter(where)
            self._select_row = None
        statement = super().selectStatement()
        print(f'selectStatement: {statement!r}')
        query = self.database().exec(statement)
        if query.lastError().isValid():
            print(f'  query-lastError: {query.lastError().text()!r}')
        else:
            print(f'  query-next: {query.next()}')
        return statement

    def revert(self):
        if BUGFIX & 1:
            self._reverting = True
        print('reverting ...')
        super().revert()
        self._reverting = False
        print('reverted')

    def submit(self):
        print('submitting ...')
        result = False if self._reverting else super().submit()
        print(f'submitted: {result}')
        return result

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('test.db')
db.open()

win = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(win)
addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add row')
layout.addWidget(addButton)
table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
layout.addWidget(table)
model = TestModel()
table.setModel(model)
submitButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit')
layout.addWidget(submitButton)
submitButton.clicked.connect(model.submitAll)
addButton.clicked.connect(lambda: model.insertRow(model.rowCount()))
app.aboutToQuit.connect(model.submitAll)

win.setGeometry(1000, 50, 640, 480)
win.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the thorough answer and testing. I'll take my time to carefully study and test it on my own, as I'd like to check it with Qt6 too (and considering that there will probably be no more OS releases of Qt5, if this was indeed fixed on Qt6 I doubt that the behavior would be fixed anyway).

Comment: @musicamante Bah, I forgot about Qt6! I've added a separate PyQt6 test script, which is needed due to breaking changes to the `QSqlField` API. However, the relevant parts of the underlying source code haven't changed (as of Qt-6.2.2), so the rest of my answer should be unaffected. Note that Qt5 LTS support runs up to June 2023, so there's still potential for fixes to be backported -  esp. as the second issue could be viewed as a security hole (although, in practical terms, I'm not sure how exploitable it is).